# Programmatically delete CCK field value

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have content type with Photos ImageField. I need to create some moderation view to show all photos and "delete" link to delete appropriate photo. How can I programmatically delete value from CCK field (in general not only ImageField but any field type)?

Comment: If i get it clear you want to remove image from your files folder as well as remove this image from content to which this image was assigned?

Comment: I'am trying to achieve the same effect as deleting image in node/edit form.

Comment: Closed as cross-site dupe: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20525/programmatically-delete-cck-field-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that since you use the term "CCK" that you are using Drupal 6.

It looks like the Drupal 6 version of the Filefield module has a suitable tidy-up function : [filefield_file_delete](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!filefield!filefield.module/function/filefield_file_delete/6). If that's the case, you can call it manually, then delete the file from the system :

```
filefield_file_delete($fileObject);
file_delete($path);
```

This will remove the file from ALL nodes referencing that file and delete it off disk.

If you are looking only to remove the reference from a single node, you can : load the node, unset the appropriate portion of the node object and resave.

Comment: Oops, missed the D6 tag in your post!